# Azure Functions: C# Get blob URI

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function which is triggered whenever an image is uploaded to a container in a Azure storage account. I read the stream and do some actions.

I would also like to get the uri of the blob that is triggering the Function but how would I do this? Do I have to work with additional inputs / outputs?

```
public static void Run(Stream myBlob, TraceWriter log) 
{
    //get byte array of the stream
    byte[] image = ReadStream(myBlob);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want the full URI, as opposed to just the blob relative path (which `string blobTrigger` would give you), you'll need to do something like this:

`public static void Run(CloudBlockBlob myBlob, TraceWriter log) 
{
    // ...
}`

At that point, you can use the [CloudBlockBlob object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.aspx) both to get the URI (e.g. `StorageUri` or some other related props) and to get the stream (e.g. `BeginDownloadToStream`). Note that when you do this, you can no longer directly receive the Stream as an input param.

Comment: I did try to use the CloudBlockBlob binding but got **Can't bind BlobTrigger to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob'** error. Would appreciate any help on this one.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the webjobs' [documentation for blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-blobs-how-to#getting-the-blob-path-for-the-triggering-blob), you can simply add a `string blobTrigger` parameter:

```
public static void Run(Stream myBlob, string blobTrigger, TraceWriter log)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your binding, you can define a variable name for blob path:

```
"path": "foo/{name}.bar",
```

Then add `name` as another function parameter:

```
public static void Run(Stream myBlob, string name, TraceWriter log)
```